# How to Calculate the total scattered radiation power and total radiation power.?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering, power, antennas

Let's suppose I have incident field $E^i_z$.
The components of Scattered electric and magnetic field are  $E^s_z$, $E^s_\phi$, $H^s_z$ and $H^s_\phi$.
The electric and magnetic field components transmitted into scattered objects are  $E^t_z$, $E^t_\phi$, $H^t_z$ and $H^t_\phi$.I don't know whether its correct or not but I used $P_s=|z_0 E_S|^2$ to calculate the total scattered radiation power where $E_s=E_z^s+E_\phi^s$ and $z_0$ is impedance in free space.Now I want to know whether my formula for scattered radiation power is correct.? Further I want to know how can I calculate the total radiation power.?